# ¿Cómo hacer un "subrayado" medio transparente y que ocupe la mitad de la línea en CSS?

Tags: css

Necesito hacer que un texto tenga un subrayado extraño y no se como aplicarlo.

El subrayado se puede ver en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo aplicar esto con CSS?

Comment: Si pudiera acceder a la pagina podria inspecionar elemento y ver como esta hecho el css pero no puedo. gracias por la respuesta igualmente

Comment: las respuestas no te sirven ?

Answer (score 3):

Acá te dejo mi compilación de efectos, ya que creo que `box-shadow` es mejor que `text-decoration` para la causa.

```css
label{
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.uno{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.dos{
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: blue;
}

.tres{
  text-decoration-line: line-through;
  text-decoration-color: blue;
}

.cuatro{
  box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 0 0 lightblue; 
}

.cinco{
  box-shadow: inset 0 -25px 0 0 lightblue; 
}
```

```html
<label class="uno">Este texto tiene un subrayado</label><br>
<label class="dos">Este texto tiene un subrayado azul</label><br>
<label class="tres">Este texto tiene una línea a través azul</label><br>
<label class="cuatro">Este texto tiene una línea atrás azul</label><br>
<label class="cinco">Este texto tiene una línea atrás azul completa</label><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que no se trata de un borde o un subrayado especial sino que lo hacen con el fondo del elemento. Con la propiedad *linear-gradient* de la regla *background* lo puedes conseguir:

```css
span{
display:inline-block;
background: linear-gradient(transparent 70%, cyan 30%) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<span>buenos días por la mañana</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

La mejor forma para mi es con `linea-gradient` y en **porcentajes**, ya que de esta forma lograr que al aumentar el tamaño de letra, este siempre conserva el mismo alto con respecto a esta.
No es necesario cambiar el `span` a `inline-block`, ya que iría seguido del resto de texto, y supongo que iría dentro de algún `p`

```css
span {
  font-size: 24px; /* no se desmaqueta al modificar el tamaño */
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 65%, #cfeffc 65%, #cfeffc 100%);
}
```

```html
<span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's </span>
```